# NEST is not returning values for an exact search

Tags: match, nest, elasticsearch-query, term-query

I am trying to build a dynamic query using NEST which is as under

```
string product = "goldpgl";            
string agencyid = "1123";


    ISearchResponse <ProductModel> res = client().Search<ProductModel>(s => s
        .Index("proddata")
        .From(0)
        .Size(100)
        .Query(q =>                            
                    +q.Term(p => p.product, product) &&                           
                    +q.Term(p => p.agencyid, agencyid)));
```

If I pass, `product value = "GoldPGL"` [ N.B.~ Real value in the index ], I am not able to find the result.

However, if I pass the value in lowercase like "goldpgl", it works.

Also, it does not work for values like "Gold - PGL" or "SOME OTHER LOAN".

My POCO is as under

```
public class ProductModel
    {
        public string product { get; set; }
        public string agencyid { get; set; }

    }
```

What is wrong and how to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not provided the mapping and search query, I am assuming its happening because you are using the [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) not the [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

Term queries are not analyzed means whatever you entered in your search query would be matched against the tokens in the index. And by default, all the text fields in Elasticsearch use the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which converts tokens to lowercase. hence `GoldPGL` doesn't match while `goldpgl` matches in your term query.

While `match` query as explained the official document is analyzed query and the same analyzer is applied on the search term, which is applied at index time, hence `GoldPGL` as well as `goldpgl` converted to `goldpgl` and both the query matches the documents and same is with `Gold - PGL` which also matches and verifies by me.

[Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) comes very handy to troubleshoot these types of issue, where search query doesn't match the indexed tokens and one example of how `GOLDPGL` would be analyzed is shown below:

POST /_analyze

```
{
    "text": "GOLDPGL",
    "analyzer" : "standard"
}

{  "token": "goldpgl",}

{
    "text": "GOLD - PGL",
    "analyzer" : "standard"
}

{
            "token": "gold",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "pgl",
            "start_offset": 7,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
```

I reproduced your issue and as I am not familiar with NEST, showing your example using the REST API.

### Index Def

POST /

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "product": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index some documents

---

POST //_doc/1

```
{
    "product": "GoldPGL"
}
```

Index 2nd doc

```
{
    "product": "Gold - PGL"
}
```

### Now search query using term query(as shown in your example), doesn't return any result (when `GoldPGL` is used)

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "product": {
                "value": "GoldPGL"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

### When used `goldgpl`, it gives result

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "product": {
                "value": "goldpgl"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "so-term-nest",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.8025915,
                "_source": {
                    "product": "GoldPGL"
                }
            }
        ]
```

### Solution (use match query)

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "product" : {
                "query" : "GoldPGL"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this return results

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "so-term-nest",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.8025915,
                "_source": {
                    "product": "GoldPGL"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: it worked to some extent. but If I pass  "SOME OTHER LOAN", it matches for that as well as for "CAR LOAN" . Means a like search is happening instead of Exact search- how to solve this ?

Comment: OK - solved it. we need to use MatchPhrasePrefix  instaed of Match. Thanks

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar, glad it helped :-)

Comment: hi, can you please help me in another requirement  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740162/how-to-make-elastic-engine-understand-a-field-is-not-to-be-analyzed-for-an-exact

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar, sure let me have a look

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar, could you please be more specific in your question, ie post your index mapping, some sample documents and expected documents for your search and search query in JSON format